# onCreateOptionsMenu opened and rotated causes E/WindowManager: Not sure if bug

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-windowmanager, android-9.0-pie, android-popupwindow

I've closed all the dialogs in my code in onDestroy() and onPause(). I've literally commented everything in my code but the onCreateOptionsMenu and still get this error. I'm basically trying to rotate the screen with the menu open and keep it open upon rotation.

I do not wish to change "*Orientation|ScreenSize*" and so on in the manifest as this is a hacky job and doesn't work as well as I have many layouts in different sizes.

My emulator is a Nexus 5X API 29 x86 (Android 9, API 28).

My onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            MenuCompat.setGroupDividerEnabled(menu, true);
            return true;
        }
```

The output

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity *"Package Name"* has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{c24148f V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-515,579} that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:511)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:346)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1434)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:1284)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(AppCompatPopupWindow.java:77)
        at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:69)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:734)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:181)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:208)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:177)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OpenOverflowRunnable.run(ActionMenuPresenter.java:806)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Unsure if this is related: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64796458

Comment: A popup like a menu is a separated `Window` floating on top of your apps "normal" `Window`, that contains your `Activity`. So I guess that's related.

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana I close the menu in onDestroy() and onPause() like seen in other threads but to no avail